# Can not find callback function of invisible reCaptcha V2

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, grecaptcha

I've spent 3 days looking for an answer, but nothing has come up

I have a website: https://rezerwacja.zuw.szczecin.pl/ There is an invisible ReCaptcha V2 on it and I need to pass it somehow to get free dates for registration

There is no confirmation form on the site, so I had to look for a callback function

The problem is that when I write

> ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].X.X

To get a callback, I find a dictionary that has a sitekey and logically there should also be a callback, but for some reason it is not there

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWriJ.png)
As you can see, there is a promise-callback but this is definitely not it
I will be very grateful if you can help me to solve the problem, thank you

i have tried to use the script of auto finding callback func but it doesn't work

```js
function findRecaptchaClients() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
  if (typeof (___grecaptcha_cfg) !== 'undefined') {
    // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase, no-undef
    return Object.entries(___grecaptcha_cfg.clients).map(([cid, client]) => {
      const data = { id: cid, version: cid >= 10000 ? 'V3' : 'V2' };
      const objects = Object.entries(client).filter(([_, value]) => value && typeof value === 'object');

      objects.forEach(([toplevelKey, toplevel]) => {
        const found = Object.entries(toplevel).find(([_, value]) => (
          value && typeof value === 'object' && 'sitekey' in value && 'size' in value
        ));
     
        if (typeof toplevel === 'object' && toplevel instanceof HTMLElement && toplevel['tagName'] === 'DIV'){
            data.pageurl = toplevel.baseURI;
        }
        
        if (found) {
          const [sublevelKey, sublevel] = found;

          data.sitekey = sublevel.sitekey;
          const callbackKey = data.version === 'V2' ? 'callback' : 'promise-callback';
          const callback = sublevel[callbackKey];
          if (!callback) {
            data.callback = null;
            data.function = null;
          } else {
            data.function = callback;
            const keys = [cid, toplevelKey, sublevelKey, callbackKey].map((key) => `['${key}']`).join('');
            data.callback = `___grecaptcha_cfg.clients${keys}`;
          }
        }
      });
      return data;
    });
  }
  return [];
}
```

It's always answering like:
[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHM6j.png)

As you can see, there is a promise-callback but this is definitely not it
I will be very grateful if you can help me to solve the problem, thank you